# Music lens does not play music through default music player

Tags: 12.04, lenses, default-programs, music-player

I have set Rhythmbox as my default music player through **System Settings > Details**, but when I browse and play music from the Unity dash, Banshee opens up and plays the music. How can I have Rhythmbox take care of this job?

Comment: This was a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-lens-music/+bug/839319) in 12.04 and earlier.  It has now been fixed but you will need to upgrade to 12.10 or later.